# How to dynamically generate <div> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to dynamically create a card, which takes in an array y.

```
createCards = (y) => {
    const matchElement = document.createElement('div');
    matchElement.classList.add('match-title'); 
    
   
        const matchInnerHTML = `    
        <div class="info>        
            <span class="number">${y[0]}</span>
        </div>
        `    
   ;
}
```

The above code works as expected. However, I want the div elements to be created dynamically as the value of i changes.

I tried to use a for loop the following way to update value of i

```
createCards = (y) => {
    const matchElement = document.createElement('div');
    matchElement.classList.add('match-title'); 

for(let i=0; i<=y.length; i++){
    const matchInnerHTML = `    
    <div class="info>        
        <span class="number">${y[i]}</span>
    </div>
    `    


 ;

matchElement.innerHTML = matchInnerHTML;
match_container.appendChild(matchElement);

}
    }
```

I'm getting undefined on my browser window. I want the cards to be generated dynamically as array gets updated.
How to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. you are creating only one div and than replacing it's innerHTML with data from the `y`. If you need multiple divs, than you need move everyting inside the `for` loop.
2. your `for` loop has an extra step, because `i` cannot be equal to `y.length`, it can only be smaller. That's why you get the `undefined` since `y[y.length]` is always `undefined`, because of first issue it only show the last item `undefined`

```js
const match_container = document.body;
createCards = (y) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    const matchElement = document.createElement('div');
    matchElement.classList.add('match-title');
    const matchInnerHTML = `    
    <div class="info>        
        <span class="number">test${y[i]}</span>
    </div>
    `
    matchElement.innerHTML = matchInnerHTML;
    match_container.appendChild(matchElement);
  }
}

createCards([1, 4, 6, 7]);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div>blah</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having a little trouble understanding your question, but hopefully this helps you accomplish your task.

```js
const anArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

const createCards = y => {
  const match_container = document.querySelector("#mc");
  const matchElement = document.createElement('div');
  matchElement.classList.add('match-title'); 

  for(let i=0; i<y.length; i++){
    const infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    infoDiv.classList.add("info");
    
    const numberSpan = document.createElement("span");
    numberSpan.classList.add("number");
    numberSpan.innerText = y[i];
    
    matchElement.appendChild(infoDiv);
    infoDiv.appendChild(numberSpan);
    match_container.appendChild(matchElement);
  }
}

createCards(anArr);
```

```html
<div id="mc"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a function that create div for each iteration in your for loop

```
const createCards = () => {
    const matchElement = document.createElement('div');
    matchElement.classList.add('match-title'); 
}

for(let i=0; i<=array.length; i++){
    createCards()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about your question is that there is a array y with several values, you want to create a list of div and each div has a span element to contain a value from y.
In this case, you can direct insert the value of y[i] inside the const matchInnerHTML. This is also the method for my similar project.

```
const matchInnerHTML = '<div class="info"><span class="number">' + y[i] + '</span></div>';
```